# Android emulator not responding after a while

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

I have a script that installs an apk file, launches it, and deinstalls it afterwards (using adb) on the android emulator. I repeat this for several apk files. 
But when I launch the android emulator, several minutes to several hours later, the emulator is not responding anymore. The spinning pinwheel appears, the only way to quit is to kill it via the terminal (using kill -9).

I have tried to change the two possible CPU/ABI Settings of an AVD to (ARM and Intelx86), but both settings result in the same problems. I have also tried different API levels (19 and 21), but also no luck there.

As I am running the emulator on a Mac, I thought the problem may be related to my OS, so I performed the same thing on a computer running Ubuntu. The same problem appears on both devices.

I have also captured the logcat files, but there are no similar error messages across these files.

These are the parameters that I am using:
Android SDK / AVD Manager on

- Mac OSX10.10 (64 bit)
- Java version 1.7.0_65

and

- Ubuntu 14.04 (64 bit)
- Java version 1.8_0.25

Any idea (why or) how to figure why the emulator is not responding anymore?

Any help would be appreciated.